# How can I capture output from LFTP? (Output not written to STDOUT or STDERR?)

Tags: curl, stderr, stdout, ftp

I would like get access to progress information from lftp. Currently, I'm using curl like so:

```
curl http://example.com/file -o file -L 2> download.log
```

This writes curl's progress information to the download.log file, which I can tail to get real-time progress.

But the same approach doesn't work with lftp, either with stdout or stderr. I end up with an empty download.log file, until the transfer is complete.

```
lftp -e 'get http://example.com/file;quit' 2> download.log
lftp -e 'get http://example.com/file;quit' 1> download.log
```

When I don't redirect output, I see progress on the screen. When I do redirect output, I stop seeing progress on the screen, but nothing shows up in download.log. After the file transfer is complete, I see the final result, like this - but nothing before:

```
97618627 bytes transferred in 104 seconds (913.1K/s)
```

Is lftp doing something unusual with its output - printing to screen without printing to stdout/stderr? Are there other ways of capturing screen output than redirecting stdout/stderr?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds to me like it's buffering its output. You might try the [unbuffer](http://expect.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/expect/expect/example/unbuffer) [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) script ([man page](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html)).

Comment: Thanks, made my day! I just added unbuffer infront and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

See for the "log:file/xfer" default setting by entering `set` command in lftp.

Possible output:

```
set log:file/xfer /home/USERNAME/.local/share/lftp/transfer_log
```

You can change this in different ways off course.

```
lftp -c 'open -e "set log:file/xfer /home/USERNAME/myown.log; mget *.csv; bye" -u uname,psswd 172.16.100.101' >> $log
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the *xfer* domain variables :

> set xfer:log 1
>
> set xfer:eta-period 5    # every 5 seconds
>
> set xfer:rate-period 20  # average rate

will put log transfer information into ~/.lftp/transfer_log

Not sure you can change the log file destination nevertheless

Comment: from the manpage:                                                                                      xfer:log-file (path to file)
              the   file  to  log  transfers  to.  Default  is ~/.local/share/lftp/transfer_log or ~/.lftp/transfer_log.

Comment: Indead! This new setting xfer-log was added in version 4.2.0 by Timur Sufiev (2011-03-03)

Answer (score -1):

try thisto capture progress info:
lftp sftp://$SFTPUSER:$SFTPPASS@$SFTPHOST -e "cd $DIRECTORY; mget $SFTPFILE; bye" > $SFTPLOG 2>&1